# Ubuntu Default LibreOffice - Is it a Snap ? Can it be?

Tags: apt, software-installation, libreoffice, snap

Ubuntu 17.10 and the upcoming 18.04. Are default programs installed as Snaps or regular type of apps? If I want to upgrade the default applications (eg LibreOffice) would I do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo snap refresh
```

And I always want the latest LibreOffice. If it's an apt-get type program (by default) how do I best remove it, and replace it with the Snap, without breaking dependencies, or causing other issues?

There's a lot of options if I recall

```
sudo apt-get purge <package-name>
sudo apt-get remove <package-name>
```

and some others I don't even recall. Can you recommend a best practice for removing programs to replace with their Snap equivalent?

Comment: I think if you need newer versions of LibreOffice you should use [their PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ubuntu/ppa). IMHO Snaps are for modern stand-alone (sometimes proprietary) applications as Skype, PyCharm, RubyMine, CLion, Brackets, VS Code and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The choice is up to the application packager**.  They can package deb or snap (or both) as they please. Either can be installed upon a new-install, or migrated upon a release-upgrade. The Ubuntu project does not have a preference.

LibreOffice, for example, is available in both deb and snap in 17.10. Note that different versions are packaged for the same release of Ubuntu:

```
$ apt show libreoffice | grep Version
Version: 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.1

$ snap search libreoffice
Name         Version  Developer  Notes  Summary
libreoffice  6.0.1.1  canonical  -      LibreOffice is a powerful office suite including word processing and creation of spreadsheets, slideshows and databases
```

The Ubuntu Desktop Team's criteria for selecting snap vs. deb for inclusion in the default install is fairly simple: Which will generate fewer bug reports and fewer support questions?

Comment: Thanks, which is the one that's actually installed by default? I assume the apt version? I won't have to `sudo snap refresh` a default install to update LibreOffice, correct?